# p3p header on GAE (Google App Engine)

Tags: google-app-engine, p3p

I'm trying to get login working with Google App Engine via an IFRAME. It works fine on Firefox, Chrome, Opera etc. Having a problem with IE, due to the "[p3p](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P3p)" issue.

The problem is I can't find a way to add the p3p header for the automatic `/_ah/openid_verify?continue=....` request, which is where the cookies are set.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there's nothing you can do at the moment to fix this issue.

The `/_ah/` URL path is reserved for features that you typically cannot modify.  In this specific case you can't add the P3P headers embedding the  "Compact Policy" that IE needs to work.

My suggestions are pretty simple:

- File a [new issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list) asking for this feature
- Switch to a self-made OpenId solution (a la [Tipfy](http://www.tipfy.org/wiki/extensions/auth/openid/) for example)